# Como detener un foreach si la condicion se cumple

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente. Tengo una variable llamada `myJson`, la cual trae un listado de usuarios, con sus respectivos valores, y cuando hago un `foreach` sobre esa variable, busco coincidencia entre el email que especifica el input y el que figura en el array

```
myJson.forEach(element => {
              if (element.email_user == this.state.email_user) {
                {
                  this.setState({ errorEmail: "Email En Uso", emailValido: "" })
                }
              } else {
                this.setState({ errorEmail: "", emailValido: "Email Valido" })
              }
            });
          })
```

El inconveniente surge que cuando hace el recorrido, encuentra la coincidencia , setea el estado correspondiente, pero luego sigue, y obviamente no encuentra mas coincidencias por lo que me queda seteado un `'Email Valido'` Cuando deberia ser un `'Email En Uso'`

Comment: Un ciclo `forEach` ni ningun ciclo tal como `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, `sort`, `for-in`, `for-of` pueden ser detenidos, ya que te dara una excepcion parecida a *illegal break statement*. y si usas `return` el ciclo simplemente hara como si fuera un `continue`,  para poder que puedas detener el ciclo forzosamente deberas usar los ciclos normales de toda la vida, ya sea `for`, `while`, `do-while` etc.

Comment: `forEach` no es un ciclo (ni `map`, ni `filter`, ni `reduce`, ni `sort`) sino un método. Es perfectamente válido usar `break` dentro de cualquier tipo de bucle tradicional, incluídos `for-in` y `for-of`.

Comment: Toda la razon amigo mio, todos esos que describiste como metodos lo son.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` no es un ciclo, sino una función que ejecuta una acción sobre cada elemento de un arreglo y no tienes como evitar que recorra todos sus elementos (por otra parte está pensada para usarse en situaciones donde sí o sí vas a recorrer todo el arreglo).

Para hacer lo que quieres puedes usar el método `find()` que te permite encontrar el primer elemento que coincide con un predicado (condición) o `filter()` que te devuelve un arreglo con todas las coincidencias.

En tu caso yo preferiría usar `filter()` puesto que: 1) sé que solo puede haber una única cincidencia; y 2) me permite usar un enfoque más funcional.

```
myJson.filter(element => element.email_user == this.state.email_user)
      .forEach(found => this.setState({ errorEmail: "Email En Uso", emailValido: "" }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Como ya te dijeron en comentarios, no se puede finalizar un ciclo *forEach*, pero puedes usar *some*:

```js
let myJson = [
    { nombre_user: 'Juan', email_user: 'juan@gmail.com' },
    { nombre_user: 'Paco', email_user: 'paco@gmail.com' },
    { nombre_user: 'Pedro', email_user: 'pedro@gmail.com' },
];

function checaMail(email_user) {
    return myJson.some(element => { return element.email_user == email_user; });
}

console.log(checaMail('maria@gmail.com'));
console.log(checaMail('juan@gmail.com'));
```